# Can I create accounts all over Stack Exchange in bulk?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

I'm tired of creating accounts. Can I spread my existing ones to other sister-sites of choice? Or to all of them at once?
If that is impossible by now, what are limitations?

I think that given enough time I could automate it by myself, but that is tedious too.

Comment: What's so tedious about signing in with your OpenID and associating it?

Comment: Eight clicks per site if done from [list of SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites). And i'm interested in most of SE sites. There are 42 of them now AFAIK. And that number of sites will grow and so will number of users with wide interests. And hacking a script isn't the best solution if owners could implement this natively.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to (unless you feel compelled to vote on something).

Just ask or answer, and once you do, you will have a cookie based registered account.

Click the "register" link at the top of the page to sign in and associate it with your other accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I have signed in with openID. It takes two clicks at a new site to login and associate with existing accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Short (but true) answer.

- You can't
- It's not so bad
- The only solution would be a sort of Stack Exchange passport, but IMO it doesn't make sense since I can't see how you would handle the rep (that should be earned on each side).

Sorry! :)